# M/M/1/N queue packet

Tags: queueing-theory

If service rate is the same as the arrival rate for M/M/1/N queue, then intuitively I think that no packets will be dropped. However, using the formula for waiting time, I get a waiting time of infinity. Can anyone help me understand this?

Answer (score 2):

There are certainly going to be dropped packets in such a queue. In the steady-state, it is completely full with probability $\frac{1}{N+1}$ - any packet arriving at such an instant is dropped.

Comment: So for example if N=10, will 10 % of packets be dropped?

Comment: If $N=10$, then in steady state $\frac{1}{11} \approx 9.1\%$ of arriving packets will be dropped.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you help me with my other queue related question please?

Comment: Can you please help me with http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/697690/statisitics-for-queueing-models