# Statisitics for queueing models

Tags: queueing-theory

I am studying various parameters related to queueing models. Does $M/M/1$ have lesser delay compared to $M/G/1$? I think yes. Can anyone verify this? How does this compare to $G/M/1$? Anyone have any resources that I can read?

Comment: What do you mean by lesser delay? A lower mean response time? This depends on the parameters. The M/M/1 queue is a special case of the M/G/1 queue. Formulas for these results can be found on wikipedia.

Comment: A lesser expected delay. I have the formulae but if either the arrival or service process is exponential how do the expected delays compare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mean response time in an [M/M/1 queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M/M/1%20queue) with arrivals at rate $\lambda$ and service at rate $\mu$ is

$$\frac{1}{\mu-\lambda}$$

while [in an M/G/1 queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollaczek%E2%80%93Khinchine_formula) with arrivals at rate $\lambda$ and service time distribution $S$ with $\mathbb E(S)=1/\mu$

$$\frac{\rho + \lambda \mu \text{Var}(S)}{2(\mu-\lambda)} + \frac{1}{\mu}$$

where $\rho=\lambda/\mu$. I don't have a formula for the G/M/1 queue to hand. We cannot write an an inequality between these two results above, it depends on the values of $\lambda$, $\mu$ and the variance of $S$. Are you interested in any particular cases?

Comment: This helps! Thank you very much

Comment: I think the result for G/M/1 is not easy, certainly the paper Chu, Y. K.; Ke, J. C. (2007). "Interval estimation of mean response time for a G/M/1 queueing system: Empirical Laplace function approach". Mathematical Methods in the Applied Sciences 30 (6): 707. doi: http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/mma.806 seems to suggest not.